# QEMU build fails to run aarch64 and arm images

Tags: arm, virtual-machine, qemu, arm64

Built qemu 2.7.0 on x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04. Running `aarch64` or `arm` guests fail with the following error,

```
qemu/build/aarch64-softmmu$ ./qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -boot d -cdrom ~/debian-8.6.0-arm64-netinst.iso  
VNC server running on 127.0.0.1:5900
qemu-system-aarch64: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x0000000008000000
This usually means one of the following happened:

(1) You told QEMU to execute a kernel for the wrong machine type, and it crashed on startup (eg trying to run a raspberry pi kernel on a versatilepb QEMU machine)
(2) You didn't give QEMU a kernel or BIOS filename at all, and QEMU executed a ROM full of no-op instructions until it fell off the end
(3) Your guest kernel has a bug and crashed by jumping off into nowhere

This is almost always one of the first two, so check your command line and that you are using the right type of kernel for this machine.
If you think option (3) is likely then you can try debugging your guest with the -d debug options; in particular -d guest_errors will cause the log to include a dump of the guest register state at this point.

Execution cannot continue; stopping here.
```

The VNC server starts almost immediately and single CPU activity spikes for around 7 seconds before the guest `tries to execute code outside RAM or ROM at ...` .
Guests include Debian 8.0 and CentOS 7.

Request suggestions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is in the error message that you quote. You are in situation (2) -- you have not provided either a kernel or a BIOS filename.

The other problem with your command line is that you've passed it a 64-bit ARM disk image but you have not used -cpu to specify that you want a 64-bit CPU. The default for the 'virt' board is 'cortex-a15' which is a 32-bit CPU.

Comment: Thank You @Peter. But, it's the same if use Debian 8.0 armhf with qemu-system-arm

Comment: That will avoid the CPU issue, but you still need to provide it either a BIOS or a kernel. QEMU for ARM targets (unlike qemu-system-x86) will not by default run a BIOS image and so will not by default be able to pull the kernel out of a disk image for you. You must either provide a BIOS image (usually UEFI) or directly pass the kernel to QEMU.

Comment: could you point me to resources that help specify a BIOS to qemu ? I'm looking at a non UEFI environment

Comment: If you're not using UEFI then you don't want to specify a BIOS (UEFI is the only BIOS that works). So you need to extract the kernel/initrd/commandline from your disk image and pass them to QEMU.

Comment: These options are generally available when using GRUB ( in grub.cfg ). How can I access them otherwise ?

Comment: If you want to run grub then you probably need to run UEFI and get that to boot grub. You have two choices: (1) run UEFI (2) directly boot a kernel image, with no bootloader or BIOS, by using the qemu -kernel/-initrd/-append arguments

Comment: @kesari: If you're looking to boot that .iso, you certainly need UEFI. Although for Debian 8, it still won't work on armhf (lack of kernel support) - current "testing" images should work, but I haven't verified it.